# In clion, rename across projects

Tags: c++, clion

I'm evaluating clion to see if I want to switch IDEs. The biggest reason to do so would be better refactoring capabilities than what I currently have (which means better than doing it all manually).

Right now, I have a library project and an app project, both C++, both Makefile projects. I want to rename a getter in the library and have usage from the app project updated. It's not currently doing that. I have both projects open although in different windows.

Is there a reasonable trick?

It's the first thing I tried to do in clion after installing it, and wanting to do refactoring was what finally nudged me to give it a try.